# First value in array is not getting updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm building a shopping cart where the user can change the amount they want to invest per asset, and then see how much their investment is worth when compounded 10% over 5 years.

I first have my Checkout component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import CartInner from "./CartInner";

export default function Checkout() {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState<any>([
    { price: 2000, id: 1 },
    { price: 4000, id: 2 }
  ]);
  const [projectedGrowth, setProjectedGrowth] = useState<any>([]);

  const handleOnChange = (index: any, e: any) => {
    const newValue = {
      price: Number(e.target.value),
      id: index + 1,
      property_id: index + 1
    };
    const newArray = [...cart];
    newArray.splice(index, 1, newValue);
    setCart(newArray);
  };

  const getGrowthAmount = (index: any) => {
    console.log(cart[index].price, "default values for price");
    const newValue = calcTotalCompoundInterest(cart[index].price, 5, 10);

    const newArray = [...projectedGrowth];
    newArray.splice(index, 1, newValue);
    setProjectedGrowth(newArray);
  };

  // whenever the cart is updated call the getGrowthAmount function
  useEffect(() => {
    for (let index = 0; index < cart.length; index++) {
      getGrowthAmount(index);
    }
  }, [cart]);

  console.log(projectedGrowth, "projectedGrowth");
  console.log(cart, "cart");

  return (
    <>
      <form className="grid gap-8 grid-cols-3">
        <div className="col-span-2">
          {cart.map((element, index) => {
            return (
              <fieldset key={index}>
                <CartInner
                  // projectedGrowth={projectedGrowth[index]}
                  element={element}
                  handleOnChange={(e) => handleOnChange(index, e)}
                  defaultValues={cart[index]?.price}
                />
              </fieldset>
            );
          })}
        </div>
          <button>Proceed to payment</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Which allows the user to change their investment amount and calculate compound interest:

```
function calcTotalCompoundInterest(total: any, year: any, rate: any) {
  var interest = rate / 100 + 1;
  return parseFloat((total * Math.pow(interest, year)).toFixed(4));
}
```

My problem is only the second value is getting updated, not the first. E.g if the first input I write 100 and the second 100,000 then the `projectedGrowth` array will return:

```
(2) [6442.04, 16105.1]
```

Which is correct for the second amount (but not for the first).

[Here's the Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/realestateinvestmentcalculator-styling-forked-fhzf58?file=/src/Form.tsx)

Here's the child component:

```
import PureInput from "./PureInput";
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";

const CartInner = React.forwardRef(
  (
    {
      handleOnChange,
      price,
      projectedGrowth,
      defaultValues,
      id,
      ...inputProps
    }: any,
    ref: any
  ) => {
    return (
          <input
            min={200}
            max={price}
            handleOnChange={handleOnChange}
            type="number"
            step={200}
            defaultValue={defaultValues}
            id={id}
            ref={ref}
            {...inputProps}
          />
    );
  }
);

export default CartInner;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

How can I get the array to return the correct compounded values (both Onload and Onchange when the user enters into the input)?

Comment: Can you remove code unnecessary to reproducing the issue? See [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with the splice. accessing the index directly from the array works

```
 const getGrowthAmount = (index: any) => {
    console.log(cart[index].price, "default values for price");
    const newValue = calcTotalCompoundInterest(cart[index].price, 5, 10);

 
    console.log(newValue, "newValue");

    projectedGrowth[index] = newValue;
    console.log(projectedGrowth, "list");

    setProjectedGrowth(projectedGrowth);
  };
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/realestateinvestmentcalculator-styling-forked-oskgdl?file=/src/Form.tsx:853-1204)

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is this one:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import CartInner from "./CartInner";

function calcTotalCompoundInterest(total: any, year: any, rate: any) {
  var interest = rate / 100 + 1;
  return parseFloat((total * Math.pow(interest, year)).toFixed(4));
}

export default function Checkout() {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState<any>([
    { price: 2000, id: 1 },
    { price: 4000, id: 2 }
  ]);
  const [projectedGrowth, setProjectedGrowth] = useState<any>([]);

  const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {};

  const handleOnChange = (index: any, e: any) => {
    console.log(index);
    const newValue = {
      price: Number(e.target.value),
      id: index + 1,
      property_id: index + 1
    };
    const newArray = [...cart];
    newArray[index] = newValue;
    setCart(newArray);
  };

  const getGrowthAmount = () => {
    const newArray = [...projectedGrowth];
    for (let index = 0; index < cart.length; index++) {
      console.log(index);
      //console.log(cart[index].price, "default values for price");
      console.log(cart);
      const newValue = calcTotalCompoundInterest(cart[index].price, 5, 10);
      newArray[index] = newValue;

      //newArray.splice(index, 1, newValue);
    }

    setProjectedGrowth(newArray);
  };

  // whenever the cart is updated call the getGrowthAmount function
  useEffect(() => {
    //for (let index = 0; index < cart.length; index++) {
    getGrowthAmount();
    //}
  }, [cart]);

  console.log(projectedGrowth, "projectedGrowth");
  console.log(cart, "cart");

  return (
    <>
      <form className="grid gap-8 grid-cols-3">
        <div className="col-span-2">
          {cart.map((element, index) => {
            return (
              <fieldset key={index}>
                <CartInner
                  // projectedGrowth={projectedGrowth[index]}
                  element={element}
                  handleOnChange={(e) => handleOnChange(index, e)}
                  defaultValues={cart[index]?.price}
                />
              </fieldset>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="bg-slate-200 p-8 flex flex-col items-stretch">
          <button>Proceed to payment</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

the error is on the `useEffect` function. In your implementation the function on all change call iteratively on the index the `getGrowthAmount` function that create a new array each time.
You should call only one time the `getGrowthAmount` function and in the cycle value the array at the index of the cycle. Then you can update pass the array to be updated.